# Faster way to find indexes that satisfy conditions within given indexes range

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 arrays, and I want to get the indexes that satisfy 2 conditions within the given index range.
Like the following, ii is the given index range.

Obtaining the indexes in array1 like "result1", or
obtaining the indexes in ii like "result2",
either way is ok.

I want to find the faster way to do this.
Any suggestion?

```
import numpy as np
import random
import time

length = 100
shape = (100,3)
array1 = np.random.randint(10,200,length)
array2 = np.random.randint(10,200,shape)
value = 20

t0 = time.time()
for i in range(1000000):
    ii = np.array(random.sample(range(0,99), 5))
    
    result1 = np.where((100 < array1[ii]) & (abs(array2[ii,2] - value) < 30))[0]

    result2 = ii[(100 < array1[ii]) & (abs(array2[ii,2] - value) < 30)]
    
t1 = time.time()
print("time: ", t1-t0)
```

Comment: You can implement this in Numba and improve the short circuiting properties of the code. If the inputs are sufficiently large (in the example they are not) you could look into improve parallel execution. Other than that I see no other area of improvement.

Comment: @norok2I tried using numba and it is faster. Thank you so much!